# Как отлаживать написанного на PHP telegram бота?

Tags: php, отладка, логирование, telegram

**Дано:**

Сделал helloworld-бота. Я могу ему послать сообщение, он дёргает телеграм, телеграм дёргает `php` скрипт, который отсылает сообщение обратно юзеру (тоже посредством дёргания телеграма).

**Задача:**

Я хочу видеть (удобно и реалтайм) те `json`, кои мне присылает телеграм и которые я ему обратно отправляю.

**Возможное решение:**

В данный момент я либо пишу из `php` скрипта нужные данные в файл и подгружаю его вручную с сервера в IDE (или просто файлом на комп) после каждого запроса. Это работает, но аццки не удобно.

**Вопрос:**

Как мне максимально удобно организовать отладку? Я привык к выводу явы в консоль `sout`-ом)

Comment: `tail -f /path/to/log.log`

Comment: @Etki, и как и куда это вбивать?..

Comment: на сервере, где выполняется код. будет выводить вам файл лога по мере его обновления

Comment: @Etki, если у меня платный хостер это тоже можно сделать?.. В смысле у меня там, насколько я знаю, не полный доступ ко всему. Хост сайта, БД, PHP, вроде и всё...

Comment: Это уже к хостеру скорее вопрос. Но я подозреваю, что хостер стоит дороже vps на том же vscale

Comment: @Etki, я понимаю, что арендовать полноценный сервер гораздо приятнее в виду гибкости настройки всего и вся, но вот в данный момент хотелось бы на том что есть работать... Я уже подумываю написать скрипт, коий мне будет инфу из моего файла просто в браузер выводить... Очень уж неудобно всё с этим PHP сделано(

Comment: Там все равно де-факто нет единого процесса, поэтому аналогичная схема с stdout не поможет. Я могу, конечно, порекомендовать вам подцепить graylog или тупо стрелять в rethinkdb, но это займет слишком много времени.

Comment: @Etki, эх... Я только половину слов понимаю(

Comment: Заходите на хост по SSH, натравливаете на файл лога `tail -f` как предлагает @Etki. Все остальное от лешего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для своих нужд сделал такой отладчик:

https://github.com/ReinRaus/telegramDebugger

Его "фишка" в том, что разработка бота ведется на локальной машине, а чтобы его отлаживать нужно писать боту в самом приложении Telegram, при этом ответы приходят обратно в приложение и видно все ошибки и предупреждения, которые произошли во время формирования ответного сообщения.

## Подключение к боту

В веб-хуке до начала работы самого бота необходимо подключить отладчик:

```
include_once( "/inc/telegramDebugger/debug.inc" );
```

В файле `index.html` необходимо указать путь к веб-хуку на localhost:

```
var localDebugger = "http://localhost/bot/hook.php";
```

## Использование

Открыть в браузере адрес:

```
http://domain.com/webhook.php?debug=manage
```

Запустить отладку для требуемых ID, чтобы узнать свой ID- после открытия адреса написать что-нибудь боту, тогда ID чата из которого было написано сообщение будет указан в "Активных чатах".
После запуска все сообщения к боту с указанных ID будут перенаправляться на localhost посредством вкладки в браузере.

Comment: Подробное описание алгоритма: http://reinraus.ru/otladka-bota-telegram-na-localhost/

Answer (score 1):

В итоге всё оказалось просто - вызываем `php` скрипт в браузере, в нём проверяем, что в переменной, куда складывается `json` от телеграмма пусто, подставляем свои значения (или `get`-ом их передаём) и видим в самом браузере всё что нужно, в т.ч. ошибки.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$action = json_decode($json, true);

if ($action != null) {
    $message = $action['message']['text'];
    $chat = $action['message']['chat']['id'];
    $user = $action['message']['from']['id'];
    $user_name = $action['message']['from']['username'];
    $first_name = $action['message']['from']['first_name'];
}
 else {

    $message = 'test';
    $chat = тут мой ИД;
    $user = тут мой ИД;
    $user_name = 'test';
    $first_name = 'testName';
    if($_GET['msg']!=null)
    {
        $message = $_GET['msg'];
    }
}

$error = 'sdfsdf
```

Соответственно теперь я могу так вызвать мой скрипт:

```
http://damain.ru/script.php?msg=fail
```

И увидеть что упало тут: `$error = 'sdfsdf`